# Public Tag on Account not Globally searchable

Tags: search-layout

I am using Public tags on Account. But, Later, I found that it is not globally searchable. Please suggest me the way out.

Comment: Can you detail the search procedure? did you try the : search all option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are searchable, at least from the Public Tags Tab. You can [add Tags to the sidebar](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_tag_add_sidebar.htm) which will take you to the tab. From there you can search through the various tags. When you click a tag, Salesforce will then show you records tagged with that tab.

[image]

You can find more information about Tags in general at https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/tag_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Watch the search all option after searching the Tag.This will give you Tag also after you click search all.Then you may get Tag.click on that to find Tag record.So will involve some Training to the end user